# adjust spacing between tables in html

Tags: html

I have 2 tables used as 2 rows for one structure:

- First Table have different width
- Second Table have different width

I set spacing parameters to 0
still there is a slight difference between first table and second table

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: please share some code ?

Comment: Show use some code, and we might be able to help...

Answer (score 0):

Probably margins or borders or padding. Heres an example with no padding and no margins.

http://jsfiddle.net/hnnAN/1/